# Trying to setup trac but failing

Tags: trac

I'm trying to setup a trac environment under Snow Leopard Server. I am now failing on the apache part.

In the apache error_log is the error

```
Oops...

Trac detected an internal error:

No module named trac.web

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/trac.fcgi", line 31, in <module>
    from trac.web import fcgi_frontend
ImportError: No module named trac.web
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the trac library isn't in your PYTHONPATH; if you're setting this up using Apache, you can add the following to your Apache config, under the `Directory` or `Location` entry for trac:

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH /path/to/trac/install
```